# Where does macOS keep VPN Network configuration?

Tags: high-sierra, vpn

I've re-installed the system and I'd like to find the location where macOS keeps the VPN configuration (in which file), the one configured in *Network*, *System Preferences*, so I am able to restore it manually from the backup files.

I've checked under `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.networkConnect.<UUID>.plist` (as per this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286348/22781)), but it looks like it's something else.

When I've manually created new VPN, I've checked the content by:

```
plutil -convert xml1 com.apple.networkConnect.*.plist -o -
```

but the VPN configuration is not there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the **Default** *profile* with **Configuration:** for the **VPN** and modifying its settings, the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist` file, the one starting in the *root* of the e.g. **Macintosh HD**, not your **Home** folder, will contain the **VPN** settings.

Also note that if you select **Add Configuration...** with **Configuration:** for the **VPN**, then some information is also stored in the `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.networkConnect.<UUID>.plist` file for the **VPN** as well.

By the way, you can use the `defaults` *command* e.g. `defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist`, to read this and other .plist files, you do not necessarily need to use `plutil` to convert to **XML** in order to read them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the `scutil` command, which should break the dependence on actual .plist file locations, which are fluid from version to version.

You can even register for notifications on networking events, such as vpn connections.

`man scutil`

Also:

```
[chiggsy:Faithless:0:~ ]$  scutil --help
usage: scutil
    interactive access to the dynamic store.

   or: scutil --prefs [preference-file]
    interactive access to the [raw] stored preferences.

   or: scutil [-W] -r nodename
   or: scutil [-W] -r address
   or: scutil [-W] -r local-address remote-address
    check reachability of node, address, or address pair (-W to "watch").

   or: scutil -w dynamic-store-key [ -t timeout ]
    -w  wait for presense of dynamic store key
    -t  time to wait for key

   or: scutil --get pref
   or: scutil --set pref [newval]
   or: scutil --get filename path key  
    pref    display (or set) the specified preference.  Valid preferences
        include:
            ComputerName, LocalHostName, HostName
    newval  New preference value to be set.  If not specified,
        the new value will be read from standard input.

   or: scutil --dns
    show DNS configuration.

   or: scutil --proxy
    show "proxy" configuration.

   or: scutil --nwi
    show network information

   or: scutil --nc
    show VPN network configuration information. Use --nc help for full command list

   or: scutil --allow-new-interfaces [off|on]
    manage new interface creation with screen locked.

   or: scutil --error err#
    display a descriptive message for the given error code
```

`scutil` with no options puts you into a shell and you can see the raw `configd` data

VPN options:

```
 scutil --nc help
Valid commands for scutil --nc (VPN connections)
Usage: scutil --nc [command]

    list
        List available network connection services in the current set

    status <service>
        Indicate whether a given service is connected, as well as extended status information for the service

    show <service>
        Display configuration information for a given service

    statistics <service>
        Provide statistics on bytes, packets, and errors for a given service

    select <service>
        Make the given service active in the current set. This allows it to be started

    start <service> [--user user] [--password password] [--secret secret]
        Start a given service. Can take optional arguments for user, password, and secret

    stop <service>
        Stop a given service

    suspend <service>
        Suspend a given service (PPP, Modem on Hold)

    resume <service>
        Resume a given service (PPP, Modem on Hold)

    ondemand [-W] [hostname]
    ondemand -- --refresh
        Display VPN on-demand information

    trigger <hostname> [background] [port]
        Trigger VPN on-demand with specified hostname, and optional port and background flag

    enablevpn <service or vpn type> [path]
        Enables the given VPN application type. Takes either a service or VPN type. Pass a path to set ApplicationURL

    disablevpn <service or vpn type>
        Disables the given VPN application type. Takes either a service or VPN type

    help
        Display available commands for --nc
```

Comment: It would be great if you can give some specific command examples which can identify `.plist` location being in use for VPN configuration. Otherwise dumping help output isn't really helpful, as I still don't know what should I look for.